# Can't send builds to Codename One server

Tags: codenameone

I can't send a build to Codename One build server anymore. Previously, I was able to "Send Android Build" successful and download the apk. Now, for whatever unknown reasons, the "Send Android Build" just ended without any errors and no apk appears in the Dashboard. (Previously, it asked me something about a certificate. I had to click OK.). I tried multiple times and nothing worked.

Then, I created a new Codename One project (a sample project with native interface). Upon sending the Build (Send Android Build) it worked - it prompted me about the certificate and the build appeared in the Dashboard.

Immediately after that, I tried to send the build again (from my app under development), it was denied with a message that I can send only one build at one time. The error message included my email address, which means it indeed logged in using my account credentials.

After some time (when the sample app was build), I did the "Send Android Build" again, and it was the same: it failed silently and there's no clue.

What could have gone wrong? What settings should I look into?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I digged further and found that there is a log message saying it has exceeded the size and I need to upgrade the account.

Well, Codename One should had put this up in a Dialog box instead of failing silently. :-)

Comment: It should have provided you a message to this effect in the output console.

Comment: It was not an "error", just "info" so the console panel did not expand. It all seemed like it ended successfully. I had to open the panel, expand the messages to see it.

Comment: That's a problem in intellij, we actually try to show a dialog but it's suppressed. We'll improve this with the next plugin update